# Authentication pattern .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am planning to create a component that will be able to check user's credentials (username and password) and, if they are valid, return associated profiles. 
I don't want to use the providers that already exist in the .Net framework (I am trying to exercise my development skills ). 
Is there any pattern I can use? Or standards?

Comment: Generally speaking, using the provided components is advised because user authentication requires secure handling of credentials, which is wrought with hazard!

To give you a better answer, give us a bit more detail: are you planning on storing creds yourself, or are you authenticating against AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The membership providers are really nice, and you can definitely exercise your dev skills even if you use them.  But you'd be developing *something other than* a user auth/profile service!.

If you truly want to roll it yourself, you need a store for the username and password hash.  When users register, have them type in the password and then hash it.  Store the username and password *hash* in whatever store you choose.  Then, when a user logs in, you hash the pw they provide and check it against the stored hash.

For the simplest cases you could just use an XML file with a list of elements, one element per user, and you can use XmlSerialization to slurp it in and save it.

```
<UserDB>
  <user>
    <name>Obsidian</name>
    <pwhash>8731876r4hndmhduihd</pwhash>
    <dateadded>2009-03-25-18:34:44</dateadded>
 </user>
</UserDB>
```

But you could also use a database, or AD/AM, some other store.

Answer (score 2):

The providers that .Net supply are all derrived from System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.

The best pattern you could follow is to write your own class that derives from [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx). That way you can write your own Authentication mechanism without having to worry about the security plumbing involved with checking authentication for every request.